# Shiro Authentication Exception after Java 1.8.0_211 Update

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat, shiro

Recently Java was updated from 1.8.0_201 to 1.8.0_211 and since then our web application Login is not working and throwing below

> Error:
>   org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException: No account information found for authentication token

Clarification Points:

1. When I switch to JRE 1.8.0_201 I am able to login without issues so
   its confirmed clash with 211 version of Java
2. Have added the -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true in Tomcat VM Arguments

Versions used:
 Shiro - 1.3.2 | Java (jre and jdk) - 1.8.0_211 | Tomcat - 8.5 | OS - 64bit    Win 10

Error Stack trace:

```
[EL Fine]: moxy: 2019-07-01 10:48:38.78--Thread(Thread[http-nio-8080-exec-5,5,main])--SAXParserFactory instance: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl@4271fc40
[EL Info]: 2019-07-01 10:48:38.933--ServerSession(792443873)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6
[EL Info]: connection: 2019-07-01 10:48:40.95--ServerSession(792443873)--/file:/C:/CapDes_WS/WS3/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/CapDes_G_DB/WEB-INF/lib/CapDes_G_Src_DB-1.25.0.569-SNAPSHOT.jar_CapDesAuth login successful
[EL Info]: connection: 2019-07-01 10:48:42.22--ServerSession(792443873)--/file:/C:/CapDes_WS/WS3/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/CapDes_G_DB/WEB-INF/lib/CapDes_G_Src_DB-1.25.0.569-SNAPSHOT.jar_CapDesAuth logout successful
[EL Info]: 2019-07-01 10:48:42.245--ServerSession(66777398)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6
[EL Info]: connection: 2019-07-01 10:48:44.222--ServerSession(66777398)--/file:/C:/CapDes_WS/WS3/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/CapDes_G_DB/WEB-INF/lib/CapDes_G_Src_DB-1.25.0.569-SNAPSHOT.jar_CapDesAuth login successful
[EL Info]: connection: 2019-07-01 10:48:45.439--ServerSession(66777398)--/file:/C:/CapDes_WS/WS3/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/CapDes_G_DB/WEB-INF/lib/CapDes_G_Src_DB-1.25.0.569-SNAPSHOT.jar_CapDesAuth logout successful
[EL Info]: 2019-07-01 10:48:45.479--ServerSession(1350484821)--EclipseLink, version: Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.4.v20160829-44060b6
[EL Info]: connection: 2019-07-01 10:48:47.509--ServerSession(1350484821)--/file:/C:/CapDes_WS/WS3/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/CapDes_G_DB/WEB-INF/lib/CapDes_G_Src_DB-1.25.0.569-SNAPSHOT.jar_CapDesAuth login successful
[EL Info]: connection: 2019-07-01 10:48:48.511--ServerSession(1350484821)--/file:/C:/CapDes_WS/WS3/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/CapDes_G_DB/WEB-INF/lib/CapDes_G_Src_DB-1.25.0.569-SNAPSHOT.jar_CapDesAuth logout successful
org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException: No account information found for authentication token [org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken - ASIAPACIFIC\inamr3, rememberMe=false] by this Authenticator instance.  Please check that it is configured correctly.
    at org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:202)
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.AuthenticatingSecurityManager.authenticate(AuthenticatingSecurityManager.java:106)
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.login(DefaultSecurityManager.java:270)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.login(DelegatingSubject.java:256)
    at com.abb.se.ppc.core.usermanagement.UserManager.isValidUserAuthentication(UserManager.java:170)
    at com.abb.se.ppc.core.usermanagement.UserManager.authenticate(UserManager.java:105)
    at com.abb.se.ppc.capdes.CapDesMainUi.authenticate(CapDesMainUi.java:170)
    at com.abb.se.ppc.client.authentication.LoginDialog$1.buttonClick(LoginDialog.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:510)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:200)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:163)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1015)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:364)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.click(Button.java:353)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$ClickShortcut.handleAction(Button.java:471)
    at com.vaadin.event.ActionManager.handleAction(ActionManager.java:238)
    at com.vaadin.event.ConnectorActionManager.handleAction(ConnectorActionManager.java:80)
    at com.vaadin.event.ActionManager.handleAction(ActionManager.java:233)
    at com.vaadin.event.ActionManager.handleActions(ActionManager.java:216)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.changeVariables(UI.java:394)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.changeVariables(ServerRpcHandler.java:608)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:458)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:408)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:273)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:90)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1422)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:379)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
10:48:49.057 [http-nio-8080-exec-5] ERROR com.abb.se.ppc.core.usermanagement.UserManager - Authentication failure for user: ASIAPACIFIC\inamr3
org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException: No account information found for authentication token [org.apache.shiro.authc.UsernamePasswordToken - ASIAPACIFIC\inamr3, rememberMe=false] by this Authenticator instance.  Please check that it is configured correctly.
    at org.apache.shiro.authc.AbstractAuthenticator.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticator.java:202) ~[shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.AuthenticatingSecurityManager.authenticate(AuthenticatingSecurityManager.java:106) ~[shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.mgt.DefaultSecurityManager.login(DefaultSecurityManager.java:270) ~[shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.login(DelegatingSubject.java:256) ~[shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at com.abb.se.ppc.core.usermanagement.UserManager.isValidUserAuthentication(UserManager.java:170) [CapDes_G_Src_DB-1.25.0.569-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.abb.se.ppc.core.usermanagement.UserManager.authenticate(UserManager.java:105) [CapDes_G_Src_DB-1.25.0.569-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.abb.se.ppc.capdes.CapDesMainUi.authenticate(CapDesMainUi.java:170) [CapDes_G_Src_DB-1.25.0.569-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at com.abb.se.ppc.client.authentication.LoginDialog$1.buttonClick(LoginDialog.java:71) [CapDes_G_Src_DB-1.25.0.569-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_211]
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:510) [vaadin-server-7.7.7.jar:7.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:200) [vaadin-server-7.7.7.jar:7.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:163) [vaadin-server-7.7.7.jar:7.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1015) [vaadin-server-7.7.7.jar:7.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:364) [vaadin-server-7.7.7.jar:7.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.click(Button.java:353) [vaadin-server-7.7.7.jar:7.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$ClickShortcut.handleAction(Button.java:471) [vaadin-server-7.7.7.jar:7.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.event.ActionManager.handleAction(ActionManager.java:238) [vaadin-server-7.7.7.jar:7.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.event.ConnectorActionManager.handleAction(ConnectorActionManager.java:80) [vaadin-server-7.7.7.jar:7.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.event.ActionManager.handleAction(ActionManager.java:233) [vaadin-server-7.7.7.jar:7.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.event.ActionManager.handleActions(ActionManager.java:216) [vaadin-server-7.7.7.jar:7.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.changeVariables(UI.java:394) [vaadin-server-7.7.7.jar:7.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.changeVariables(ServerRpcHandler.java:608) [vaadin-server-7.7.7.jar:7.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:458) [vaadin-server-7.7.7.jar:7.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:408) [vaadin-server-7.7.7.jar:7.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:273) [vaadin-server-7.7.7.jar:7.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:90) [vaadin-server-7.7.7.jar:7.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41) [vaadin-server-7.7.7.jar:7.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1422) [vaadin-server-7.7.7.jar:7.7.7]
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:379) [vaadin-server-7.7.7.jar:7.7.7]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [servlet-api.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449) [shiro-web-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365) [shiro-web-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90) [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83) [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383) [shiro-core-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362) [shiro-web-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125) [shiro-web-1.3.2.jar:1.3.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [catalina.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.15]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_211]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.5.15]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_211]
Jul 01, 2019 10:48:49 AM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
SEVERE: 
java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.util.Optional.get(Optional.java:135)
    at com.abb.se.ppc.core.usermanagement.UserManager.authenticate(UserManager.java:120)
    at com.abb.se.ppc.capdes.CapDesMainUi.authenticate(CapDesMainUi.java:170)
    at com.abb.se.ppc.client.authentication.LoginDialog$1.buttonClick(LoginDialog.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.vaadin.event.ListenerMethod.receiveEvent(ListenerMethod.java:510)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:200)
    at com.vaadin.event.EventRouter.fireEvent(EventRouter.java:163)
    at com.vaadin.server.AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(AbstractClientConnector.java:1015)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.fireClick(Button.java:364)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button.click(Button.java:353)
    at com.vaadin.ui.Button$ClickShortcut.handleAction(Button.java:471)
    at com.vaadin.event.ActionManager.handleAction(ActionManager.java:238)
    at com.vaadin.event.ConnectorActionManager.handleAction(ConnectorActionManager.java:80)
    at com.vaadin.event.ActionManager.handleAction(ActionManager.java:233)
    at com.vaadin.event.ActionManager.handleActions(ActionManager.java:216)
    at com.vaadin.ui.UI.changeVariables(UI.java:394)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.changeVariables(ServerRpcHandler.java:608)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocation(ServerRpcHandler.java:458)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleInvocations(ServerRpcHandler.java:408)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.ServerRpcHandler.handleRpc(ServerRpcHandler.java:273)
    at com.vaadin.server.communication.UidlRequestHandler.synchronizedHandleRequest(UidlRequestHandler.java:90)
    at com.vaadin.server.SynchronizedRequestHandler.handleRequest(SynchronizedRequestHandler.java:41)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinService.handleRequest(VaadinService.java:1422)
    at com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet.service(VaadinServlet.java:379)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:449)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:365)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:383)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:362)
    at org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:125)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: What is the full stacktrace?  What does your log show?    https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have added the Full stacktrace of the error, but strangely this error is not appearing and sign in is successful using Java 1.8.0_212 update.

Comment: @BrianDemers Any update on the issue with 211 update, as we are not sure which java version will be updated in the prod server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the issue was with the Certificate itself. Below are the steps followed:

1. Check the present version of Java- java -XshowSettings:properties –version
2. Know the location of the Server certificate (adserver.crt) or get it with the help of IT team.
3. switch to cd- C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_\bin
4. Run- keytool -import -keystore “c:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_\lib\security\cacerts” -alias  -file D:\adserver.crt
5. Restart the server

The issue will be solved.
root_base64.cer can be used if in case adserver.crt doesn't work, also make sure to remove the one which didn't work before adding another.